# Using Stored Procedures Vs Embedded Queries in Tibco BW

Tags: tibco

Today we got a new direction from management to use only stored procedures instead of SQL queries in Tibco BW. I'm new to tibco and worked only in couple of projects. Can someone help me to understand what added advantage will bring if we use stored procedure in Tibco? Also every process might be using 10 different queries. So if we add that many stored procedures and create indexes and maintain them is it worth on the whole for 50+ processes? I'm having hard time to present Advantages Vs disadvantages

Answer (score 0):

People are used to queries and this is why a lot of times are skeptical when it comes to Stored Procedures. Use your databases' capabilities at its fullest. Do not depend only on your back end programming language. Database programming is very powerful. Stored procedures for complicated logic are usually faster than your typical query. Make sure you plan carefully what the Stored Procedure needs to do and also different scenarios within the stored procedure. Once you get used to it you will not want to do not use them.

The secret is to maintain a current and well written documentation of your stored procedures.